# GAE Cloud-sql-proxy - How to connect to two DB locally?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I try to connect to two different Cloud MySCQL Databases instances for one GAE project. Locally i try to put first to 127.0.0.1:3307, scond to 127.0.0.1:3308.

I execute:

```
$ C:\\...\cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances=mypoject:region:first_db=tcp:3307, myproject:region:second-db=tcp:3308
```

But it seems like run only first_db. The second won`t run. MySQL client can`t connect to db on port 3308.

Output of previous execution cloud_sql_proxy.exe:

```
YY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS Listening on
> 127.0.0.1:3307 for mypoject:region:first_db YY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS 
Ready for new connections
```

What's the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Issue is solved simply.  It may to run two separate cmd-administrator mode window and run each instance in diff window. MySQL normally see it together ))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#tcp).

You should have run the proxy `instances` argument without white-spaces.

`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myProject:us-central1:myInstance=tcp:3306,myProject:us-central1:myInstance2=tcp:3307`

Answer (score 1):

Issue is solved.

I solved it by running two separate cmd window (Admin mode) and run each cloud-sql-proxy instance in diff window.